# Exception: Service Slides failed while accessing document with id XYZ........ at refreshSlides(Code:6:7)

Tags: google-apps-script, google-slides

I am trying to run the same script in multiple Google Slides files. Each document has only one slide.

It is a simple script to automatically update the slide on each document on a periodic basis (refreshing the slide includes updating a graph/chart which has been updated elsewhere). I set a trigger for the script to fire every minute.

The code from my script is below. I validated that it worked on the first Google Slides document I tried it on (still works on that document). On every other document, the script fails every time it is run with the following error:

> Exception: Service Slides failed while accessing document with id XYZ........ at refreshSlides(Code:6:7)

The document ID is a full ID which I believe references the associated Google Slides document ID.

Steps I have taken to troubleshoot to no avail:

- Tried changing function names on each document's script
- Tried changing variable names on each document's script
- Tried the trigger with various deployment types (Head, Version 1, and Version 2)

Script code:

```
function refreshSlides(){
// var gotSlides = SlidesApp.getActivePresentation().getSlides();
var presentation = SlidesApp.getActivePresentation().getSlides();
for (var i = 0; i < presentation.length; i++) {
var slide = presentation[i];
slide.refreshSlide();
// var sheetsCharts = slide.getSheetsCharts();
}
};
```

I expected the script to run on each document without issue. However, all executions (except for those on the first document) have failed.

Comment: Can you provide a sample Google Slides for correctly replicating your current issue of `Exception: Service Slides failed while accessing document with id XYZ........ at refreshSlides(Code:6:7)` using your showing script?

Comment: Welcome to [so]. Do you have a single Google account or do you have more? Do you use multiple sign in? How do you passed the code from one presentacion ot the others? Are you the owner of all presentations?